# Weceem plugin unable to edit content

Tags: javascript, html, grails, content-management-system, weceem

recently I have been trying to install weceem 1.2-M1 plugin on grails but it just refuses to let me edit content. Whenever I try to edit content, a chunk of JS is served as text in the header of the page(sorry cant post pictures yet).

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> function styleButtons() { $('button.removeTag').button({ icons: { primary: 'ui-icon-closethick' }, text: false }); } $(function() { styleButtons(); $('button.addTag').button(); /*{icons: { primary: 'ui-icon-plus' }});*/ $('#tagsfield_tags .addTag').click( function(event) { event.preventDefault(); var dataElem = $("input[name='tags']"); var existingTags = dataElem.val().split(','); var displayTagsParent = $("#tagsfield_tags .existingTagList"); var newTagsElem = $("input[name='newTags_tags']"); var newTags = newTagsElem.val().split(','); var exists = false; $.each(newTags, function(index, t) { t = $.trim(t).toLowerCase(); var exists = false for (i = 0; i < existingTags.length; i++) { if (existingTags[i] == t) { exists = true; break; } } if (!exists) { existingTags[existingTags.length] = t; $('<div class="existingTag"><span class="tagtext">'+t+'</span><button class="removeTag">Remove</button></div>').appendTo(displayTagsParent); styleButtons(); } }) dataElem.val(existingTags.join(',')); newTagsElem.val(''); }); $('#tagsfield_tags .removeTag').live('click', function(event) { event.preventDefault(); var tagParentDiv = $(event.target).parentsUntil('.existingTagList'); var tagToRemove = $('.tagtext', tagParentDiv).text(); $(tagParentDiv).fadeOut(500, function() { $(this).remove(); }); var dataElem = $("input[name='tags']"); var currentTags = dataElem.val().split(','); var newVal = ''; $.each(currentTags, function(index, t) { t = $.trim(t).toLowerCase(); if (t != tagToRemove) { newVal += t + ',' } }); dataElem.val(newVal); }); }); </script>
```

I have already included the 2 lines below into the Config file.

```
grails.resources.adhoc.excludes = ['/plugins/weceem-1.2-M1/*']  
grails.mime.disable.accept.header.userAgents = ['Gecko', 'WebKit', 'Presto', 'Trident']
grails.mime.file.extensions = false
grails.mime.types = [ // the first one is the default format
all:           '*/*', // 'all' maps to '*' or the first available format in withFormat
atom:          'application/atom+xml',
css:           'text/css',
csv:           'text/csv',
form:          'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
html:          ['text/html','application/xhtml+xml'],
js:            'text/javascript',
json:          ['application/json', 'text/json'],
multipartForm: 'multipart/form-data',
rss:           'application/rss+xml',
text:          'text/plain',
hal:           ['application/hal+json','application/hal+xml'],
xml:           ['text/xml', 'application/xml']
]
grails.resources.adhoc.excludes = ['/plugins/weceem-1.2-M1/*']  
//grails.resources.adhoc.patterns = ['/images/*', '/css/*', '/js/*', '/plugins/*']
```

and this is my buildconfig file

```
plugins {
    checksums false
    build ":tomcat:7.0.50"
    compile ":twitter-bootstrap:3.1.0"
    compile ":scaffolding:2.0.1"
    compile ':cache:1.1.1'
    compile ":jquery:1.8.3"
    compile ":jquery-ui:1.8.24"
    compile (':weceem:1.2-M1')
    compile ":hibernate:3.6.10.7"
    runtime ":database-migration:1.3.8"
    compile ":resources:1.2.1"
    runtime ":twitter-bootstrap:3.0.3"
    }
```

and lastly, here is my urlmapping
    class UrlMappings {

```
static mappings = {
   // "/$controller/$action?/$id?(.$format)?"{
   //     constraints {
   //         // apply constraints here
   //     }
   // }

    //"/"(view:"/index")
    "500"(view:'/error')
}
}
```

Con somebody help me figure out what's wrong or point me to the right direction? thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

What about your security settings for plugin? Maybe you don't have rights to edit content? You can check demo application with weceem plugin, see http://www.weceem.org/weceem/ or https://github.com/jCatalog/weceem-app for example of configuration.